# How to parse array data to render radar graph

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I have an array coming from API as this one

```
var inputData = [{
  gap: 3,
  myideal: 7,
  myself: 4,
  theme_id: 1,
  theme_name: "feedback"
}, {
  gap: 4,
  myideal: 5,
  myself: 1,
  theme_id: 2,
  theme_name: "delegation"
}, {
  gap: 4,
  myideal: 8,
  myself: 4,
  theme_id: 3,
  theme_name: "communication"
}, {
  gap: 2,
  myideal: 7,
  myself: 5,
  theme_id: 4,
  theme_name: "time_management"
}, {
  gap: 6,
  myideal: 10,
  myself: 4,
  theme_id: 5,
  theme_name: "performance"
}, {
  gap: 2,
  myideal: 10,
  myself: 8,
  theme_id: 6,
  theme_name: "team"
}];
```

and i want to convert this array to usable format so i can render a radar chart, I am expecting my array as

```
const resultData = [{
  key: 'myideal',
  label: 'myideal',
  values: {
    feedback: 7,
    communication: 8,
    team: 10,
    delegation: 5,
    time_management: 7,
    performance: 10,
  },
}, {
  key: 'myself',
  label: 'myself',
  values: {
    feedback: 4,
    communication: 4,
    team: 8,
    delegation: 1,
    time_management: 5,
    performance: 4,
  },
}]
```

Is it possible to do it using lodah or native methods, i tried so many lodash methods like groupBy, chaining, etc., but i could not find a way to get it in preferred format, any help appreciated.

here is the [link to jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4wse6Lho/2/)

Thanks.

Comment: Can you add more information about array conversion?

Comment: each object had theme_name and myself and myideal. So basically i would like to transform it to myself, myideal with all theme_name and its value for this group (myideal or myself)

Answer (score 0):

You can map `['myideal', 'myself']` into an array of objects like this

```js
const inputData = [{
  gap: 3,
  myideal: 7,
  myself: 4,
  theme_id: 1,
  theme_name: "feedback"
}, {
  gap: 4,
  myideal: 5,
  myself: 1,
  theme_id: 2,
  theme_name: "delegation"
}, {
  gap: 4,
  myideal: 8,
  myself: 4,
  theme_id: 3,
  theme_name: "communication"
}, {
  gap: 2,
  myideal: 7,
  myself: 5,
  theme_id: 4,
  theme_name: "time_management"
}, {
  gap: 6,
  myideal: 10,
  myself: 4,
  theme_id: 5,
  theme_name: "performance"
}, {
  gap: 2,
  myideal: 10,
  myself: 8,
  theme_id: 6,
  theme_name: "team"
}];

const expectedResult = ['myideal', 'myself'].map((key) => {
    let values = {};
    inputData.forEach((data) => {
        values[data.theme_name] = data[key]
    })
    return {key: key, label: key, values}
});

// alternately you can use `Array.reduce` as well
const expectedResultReduce = ['myideal', 'myself'].map((key) => {
  return {
    key: key, 
    label: key, 
    values: inputData.reduce((acc = {}, data) => {
      return {...acc , [data.theme_name]: data[key]};
    }, {})
  }
}); 

console.log(expectedResult)
console.log(expectedResultReduce)
```